# How can I concatenate two different model query and order by a field that both models has

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I concatenate two different model query and order by a field that both models has like progress fields.

**For example**

*models.py*

```
class Gig(models.Model):
    author= models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharFields()
    progress = models.IntegerField()

class Project(models.Model):

    author= models.ForeignKey(User)

    title = models.CharFields()

    progress = models.IntegerField()
```

Can I do my view.py like this, for me to achieve it?

İf No, How can I achieve it?

*views.py*

```
def fetch_all_item(request):
   gig = Gig.objects.filter(author_id = request.user.id)
   project = Project.objects.filter(author_id = request.user.id)
   total_item = (gig + project).order_by("progress")

   return render(request, "all_product.html", {"item": total_item})
```

I am trying to join two query set from **Gig** and **Project** models then send it to frontend in an **ordering** form by a **field** name called **progress**.

Comment: Why do you use two models for this? Why not a field `type` that specifies if it is a `Project` or `Gig`?

Comment: Found this that might help https://howchoo.com/django/combine-two-querysets-with-different-models

Comment: Because of both model don't have similar fields but they both have **progress** field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let Python do the sorting for you, like:

```
from operator import attrgetter


def fetch_all_item(request):
    gig = Gig.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    project = Project.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    total_item = sorted([*gig, *project], attrgetter('progress'))
    return render(request, "all_product.html", {'item': total_item})
```

It might however be better to remodel this to a single model with a `type` field that disambiguates between a `Gig` and a `Project`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

In general, such design when there are common fields is better accomplished by inheriting from some base class. E.g.:

```
class CommonActivity(models.Model):
    # common fields for Project/Gig
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharFields()
    progress = models.IntegerField()

class Gig(CommonActivity):
    pass   # or other fields related to Gig only

class Project(CommonActivity):
    pass
```

Then if you want to query both - you query `CommonActivity`.

If remodel not possible - then filter via Python as @WillemVanOnsem suggested.

However such filtering will be way less efficient

Comment: If you want to use this approach, the django documentation has a section about model inheritance, which I highly recommend reading. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: Thank you @Egor Wexler, I didn't have any issue with the models but I want to join two models together and order by a field